# How could I make this for loop end without stopping it from splitting the text

Tags: python, for-loop, split, os.system

I know that sounds like an insane question but I want to use the x variable in the command being sent to terminal and i have no other ideas on how to use it. I'm very new to python.

```
def words(filepath):
    with open(filepath,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for x in line.split():
                ## i tried adding yield x here and that didnt seem to work
                ## how the hell do i end this for loop

                
words = words('/users/zac/test.txt')
for x in words:
    os.system('osascript send.scpt {} "{}"'.format('5555555555', x ))
```

Comment: Do you need the function `words` to return all the words in `test.txt` and then run "osascript" on each word ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you get an error message when running this (with `yield x`) ? you also need to use `f.readlines()` like in mobiusxs' answer.

Comment: If the file isn't too long you could do something like: `with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f: words = f.read().split()`, then `words` will be all the "words" in the file (you can use `re.split` for more control over splitting).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use yield here to make it a generator. You probably want to iterate over the lines of the file rather than characters. You need to use:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    for word in line.split():
        yield word
```

Comment: You should clean up your format string in your system call as well: `os.system(f'osascript send.scpt 5555555555 "{x}"')`